# Realm. Get subset of inner element based on outer one

Tags: realm, nosql

There is a structure:

```
{ "groups": [ 
     { "gid" : 1, 
       "elements" : [ 
              { "eid" : 1 }, 
              { "eid" : 2 } 
       ] 
     }, 
     { "gid" : 2, 
       "elements" : [ 
              { "eid" : 11 }, 
              { "eid" : 22 } 
       ] 
     }
     { "gid" : 3, 
       "elements" : [ 
              { "eid" : 21 }, 
              { "eid" : 32 } 
       ] 
     } 
  ] 
}
```

I understand how to get all groups:

```
RealmResults<Group> all = realm.where(Group.class).findAll();
```

Also I could get all elements or all elements in a group.

But how could I query all element from groups that have id > 1?

```
RealmResults<Group> allFilteredGroups = realm.where(Group.class).greaterThan("gid", 1).findAll();
```

Is it possible to retrive all elements from all `allFilteredGroups` by one query, smth like

```
realm.where(Element.class).equalsTo(???, allFilteredGroups).findall() ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "to retrieve all elements". `allFilteredGroups` has all the `Group` objects. As they are linked to the `Elements` objects, you can easily iterate through them:

```
for(Group group : allFilteredGroups) {
    for(Element element : group.getElement()) {
        Log.d("TEST", "eid = " + element.eid);
    }
}
```

There is currently no easy way to flatten the last and have all the `Element` objects in a single `RealmResults`.

Comment: Is it possible to find how many elements are in allFilteregGroups? Smth like allFilteredGroups.smth().sum("elements.size")? Or I only can iterate over all of the collection and sum it by myself?

Comment: You will have to iterate.